# TortoiseSVN can't connect to SlikSVN Subversion server

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I've created a SubVersion server on one of the machines in my workgroup. From my development box I'm able to access the repository and check in/out files without any problem.

I've just installed TortoiseSVN and no matter what I do it won't connect to the repository on the server. I get the infamous error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be..? As far as I know, the tortoise shell extension is running under my user credentials. It seems strange that the SVN command line tools work correctly, but not Tortoise.

Both machines are running Vista

*NOTE: In both cases I'm using the svn protocol to connect*

*Finally, I've fixed it...!
The problem seems to be with the Subversion package I downloaded. I downloaded the latest version of SlikSVN (1.5.5) and installed it on my client and server. It seems TortoiseSVN doesn't like this build/version. I just uninstalled SlickSVN on both machines and grabbed the latest version from CollabNet and now everything works as expected!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I've fixed it...!

The problem seems to be with the Subversion package I downloaded. I downloaded the latest version of SlikSVN (1.5.5) and installed it on my client and server. It seems TortoiseSVN doesn't like this build/version. I just uninstalled SlickSVN on both machines and grabbed the latest version from CollabNet and now everything works as expected!

Answer (score 6):

Just add `--listen-host 0.0.0.0` to your SVN service command. The problem is that you are creating the service listening to `IPv6` and you are trying to access it using `IPv4`. Look at this:

http://www.renaissance-design.net/code/installing-and-configuring-svnserve-and-tortoisesvn-on-windows/

Answer (score 2):

You might want to ask this question on the TSVN mailing list:

See http://tortoisesvn.net/community or http://groups.google.com/group/tortoisesvn

You will usually get an answer very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following:

- is your firewall configured to let traffic through (port 3690, by default, or any other port you might have svnserve configured to run on). Check firewalls both on your client machine and on the machine you run svnserve.
- many virus scanners also interfere with 'unusual' network ports
- the default host svnserve is listening on is 'localhost', which means you won't be able to connect to it from another machine. Did you start svnserve with the '--listen-host serverhostname' param?

Edit:
if you're using the collab.net server, you have to start the service manually:

```
net start svnserve
```

Also this might help: http://subversion.open.collab.net/articles/svnserve-service.htm

Comment: There's no firewall enabled on the server, but there is on the client. I've configured the client firewall to allow port 3690. The only virus scanner is Windows Defender. I've tried the --listen-host setting but it makes no difference

Comment: I use c:\svn\bin\svnserve.exe --service -r c:\repository
(note: I took out --listen-host as it made no difference).
Like I said in my post, everything works find using the subversion command line tools. It's when I try from Tortoise that I get problems

Comment: You first have to install the service if you're starting svnserve with the --service flag.
See this blog post:
http://subversion.open.collab.net/articles/svnserve-service.htm

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth checking that Tortoise hasn't picked up on a proxy setting (Network settings in Tortoise config).  From the same screen you can open the SVN server file and see if there's anything weird going on in there.

Comment: I checked that and everything is commented out :-(

Comment: Bummer. Can you try it with another protocol like HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

What protocol are you using to access the server-side repository? If it's not a `file://` protocol, have you confirmed that the corresponding server is actually running? Try to connect to it manually, for example by running

`telnet target.machine.ip.address target_port`

(of course, replacing `target.machine.ip.address` by the actual IP address and `target_port` by the numeric server port). If that port is open, the screen will clear, otherwise telnet will hang for a while then complain.

If it works using the IP address and not the machine's name, you have a problem in name resolution (check your DNS and/or WINS settings.)

Comment: I'm using SVN as the protocol and the server is running. I'm able to connect to it via the command line and even through a web browser!

Comment: Sorry, but unless you have the svnprotocolhandler installed, you can not browse an svnserve served repository with a browser!
Do you maybe have Apache installed? Then you have to use the http or https urls instead of the svn:// urls.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with SlickSVN 1.5.5. But in my case it was local subversion server running in deamon mode. CollabNet package works fine with the same configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The Slik Subversion Client is IPv6 and IPv4 enabled, so if your system says it prefers IPv6. With the --listen-host argument you can choose how it should listen.

Answer (score 0):

I re-ran the command `svnserve --daemon --root D:\Subversion\Repo`, and this resolved this error.

This error came up suddenly. We were working fine one minute, and the next we saw this error. Not sure why.