# Subversion Server to use on Windows

Tags: .net, svn, tortoisesvn

What Subversion (SVN) Server would recommend a newbie get started on the Windows Server OS?

I think I'll be using TortoiseSVN on the client and will be doing .NET development mostly.

**UPDATE:**
Great advice. I'm picking my answer based on votes. I will try VisualSVN and CollabNet.
Please read chyne's answer which I thought was really good too (+1). I'll try that method out too.

I'll come back to this question in a week or two an update with my thoughts in the comments.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I use [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) server and find it really easy to setup and use.

Also if you're doing .NET development, look into [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) for Visual Studio integration. I have both that and tortoise SVN installed as clients.

Comment: Just be sure to download the server, because they also make a client. The server is free, while the client is not so free. But yeah, VisualSVN is pretty neat.

Comment: This is what we use, great stuff

Comment: Along with the VisualSVN server I use the VisualSVN client and I think it's well worth the few $ for nice Visual Studio integration.

Comment: Given how much effort goes into TortoiseSVN, it makes me feel a little sad for Stefan, Simon and everyone on the TortoiseSVN team to see others profiting from their work. Yes I understand FLOSS, and perhaps VisualSVN donate to TortoiseSVN, but I can't tell, and IMHO it would be nice if they did.

Comment: VisualSVN server works well. Easy to setup and implement. Been using it for 4 years now without a single issue.

Comment: For my relatively simple home projects VisualSVNServer is more than enough. Wish it had some kind of web administration UI, but then again I don't really have much to administrate anyway. Running VisualSVNServer on Windows 2012 Standard just fine so far. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 13):

Just use the standard windows distribution of the [SVN server](http://subversion.tigris.org/), running as a service. It works perfectly fine for me. I use TortoiseSVN for the client, as well.

Comment: Where is the standard distribution? Is that CollabNets?

Comment: Some instructions for setting up svnserve on windows
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html#tsvn-serversetup-svnserve-2

Answer (score 6):

If you're talking one person, just getting started, working on your own personal projects on a single PC, then I would recommend starting with a file system based repository and skip the server altogether. Keep it simple.

TortoiseSVN can create a local repository (on a network drive, or external drive if you need the safety of having your working copy and repository in different places).

Just create a folder somewhere for your repository, right-click it and use Tortoise's "Create Repository Here" command.

The URL of your repository will then be something like: `file:///X:/path/to/repository`.

You can always move your repository to a server later if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

[sliksvn](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download) simple, free and just works - runs as a service, no need for a web server.

Answer (score 2):

Visual SVN is great, but I found it a little too magical.

I set mine up following the directions from Code Magazine.

http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0807081

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with SlickSVN as you can read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410844/tortoisesvn-cant-connect-to-machine-in-workgroup). In the end I went with the CollabNet binaries.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just go for the basic run of the mill [SVN server](http://www.collab.net/servlets/OCNDirector?id=CSVN1.5.6WINS) package, especially since you'll be using Tortoise.
It's lean :)

Answer (score 0):

I often use TortoiseSVN in combination with the offical simple Subversion server that's included with the official Subversion Windows binaries. I've created a simple batch script file that starts the server when I need it. Here it is:

```
@echo Starting SVNServe in daemon mode...
C:\Utils\SVN\bin\svnserve.exe -d -r C:\Repositories
```

As you can see I keep my repositories in C:\Repositories.

Ofcourse this is a very simple approach. If you want more security, you'd probably host the repositories on a different server etc. But on the other hand this is very easy to manage.