# A Subversion server for windows (SVN) for Tortoise Client

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

My question is like this one:
[Subversion Server to use on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615866/subversion-server-to-use-on-windows)

The only problem is that it's old and I can see Subversion server on windows requires Apache and something like. I'm looking for:

- Windows 7 64x (not Windows Server)
- SVN Server with free commercial license or GNU
- That works with Tortoise client
- That works without any server or plugin of something, just an application or service.
- That have statistics of work.

Please before answer or comment review if the suggested application is applicable to this requirement.

Comment: Tortoise SVN is just a front end for the SVN client, I don't think it's meant to work with an SVN server.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Visual SVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) meets all of your requirements (save the last one, which I do not understand).

- Compatible with Windows 7 x64
- Free commercial license (as far as I understand it)
- Works with TortoiseSVN
- It requires Apache, I think, but it's embedded in a way that I can't readily perceive. It's a Windows service, regardless, and dead simple to set up.

And it was last updated about two weeks ago (2012-05-18), so not exactly old.

Comment: I think he probably meant "statistics".

Comment: Hmm. If so, TortoiseSVN has some, very minimal, repo stats. Though I hate them. I can inflate my commits, Mr. Manager, if I commit one file at a time...

Comment: * VisualSVN Server provides advanced logging (access / operational) to Windows Eventlog in the paid Enterprise Edition. 

* You can always write a script in C#, VB.Net and VBScript to gather statistics and output them in a preferred format (though I don't understand what statistics were mentioned in the original question).

Comment: Visual SVN Server doesn't require Apache, you can use it with svnserve.

Comment: Update: Starting version 4.x, VisualSVN doesn't provide free commercial licence anymore. Refer the latest licensing at [here](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/licensing/).

Answer (score 6):

Nobody mention, instead of giant 3-rd party applications, [svnserve](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html) for creating svn://-based repositories:

- svnserve is part of any Subverson installation
- it's small
- it have easy and fast start
- doesn't require long and complex configuration steps
- can work as a service

Answer (score 5):

Depending on which requirements you have (I don't think that your list is complete), it may be sufficient to use TortoiseSVN only.

The requirements then should include:

- I am the only user of the Subversion repository.
- All of the users have access to the server.
- You don't want to have access rules  that restrict access to parts of the repository.

Then you can do the following:

- Create a new subversion repository on the server by using the command ["Create Repository Here"](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-qs-guide.html#tsvn-qs-repo).
- [Checkout that repository](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-qs-guide.html#tsvn-qs-wc) by giving as URL something like `file:///c:/svn_repos/trunk/` (which of course depends on the location of your repository).

To derive statistics for your repository, you could use [StatsSVN](http://wiki.statsvn.org/) which is independent how you operate your repository.

Answer (score 1):

[uberSVN](http://ubersvn.com) meets all your requirements, and a few more bits as well.

- Windows 7 64x (not Windows Server)
- SVN Server with free commercial license or GNU
- That works with Tortoise client
- That works without any server or plugin of something, just an application or service - SVN needs apache but this is installed and run as part of uberSVN
- That have statics of work. - you can see and comment on work that people have done, and there are some extra social features for teams of users

Comment: As of 2014 UberSVN is now defunct.