# Connect SVN repository folder from old hard drive

Tags: svn

I have folders from an old harddrive that were subversion repositories on the server the drive came from.  These are in the form of:

```
<svn-name>
    db
     |- revprops
     |- revs
     |- transactions
     |- txn-protorevs
     current
     txn-current
```

The original server was Debian Linux if that's relevant.  The files are now on a Windows 10 machine.  The original machine, and in fact the original drive is long gone so remounting to a similar architecture isn't an option.

I need to access the repositories long enough to ensure that all files in them have been transferred to another location.  Essentially I want to check out everything in the repository.

I can either set up a subversion server on my Windows machine temporarily ( I have no need for that long term), set up the server on an alternate (Debian) server, or some other mechanism I'm not aware of that someone suggests.

What's the best approach to do this, and assuming I'm setting up an SVN server somewhere, how do I connect to these existing folders?

I did use TortoiseSVN and try file://repository-name, which didn't work.  I assume that's because I don't actually have an SVN server on the machine I'm using.

Help?

Edit: exploring the path of possibly installing an SVN server on my Windows SVN, I found a suggestion [in this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780066/a-subversion-server-for-windows-svn-for-tortoise-client) about just doing what I needed to do with ToroiseSVN using the "create repository here" command.  I tried this, which required an empty folder, and then copied the db folder over to the repo from the old harddrive folder.

That gave me the tags/trunk folder structure from the old repo, but no files.

Edit 2:  Turns out, this actually does work.  The repository folder I tried for my first attempt didn't actually have any files in it.  I'm going to answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Much like the discussion linked in my question above, as the sole user needing to access a repository on my local drive, I was able to just use TortoiseSVN to solve my problem.

- Install TortoiseSVN client on my Windows machine containing the repository folders
- Create a new empty folder with the repository name
- Use the TSVN command "create repository here" to create a repository in the empty folder
- copy the DB folder from the original repository folder to the one created above, overwriting the contents of that folder in the new repository
- Navigate to the new repository in Explorer, right click and select the repo browser.  Voila!

From research, many claim that such antics aren't necessarily guaranteed to work by the Subversion folks, so YMMV.

Comment: This procedure is unnecessarily superfluous IMO. Normally, the `svn checkout file:///C:\pathtorepository` command or checking out the local URL `file:///C:\pathtorepository`with TortoiseSVN will give you the same results. Note that replacing the DB directory of another repository may work, but can also create an unreadable (or otherwise problematic) repository. You shouldn't touch the repository backend files in 99.9% of cases.

Comment: @bahrep as indicated in my question, I attempted the file:// approach simply using the repo browser and it failed indicating that it was unable to connect to the repository.  I note though that in my syntax it was file:// and in your comment it's file:/// (note the extra /)  Did I misread the correct way to use file: or is that a typo in your comment?

Comment: it's three slashes. Note that you don't have to enter the file:/// URL manually. You can right-click your repo's directory and select TortoiseSVN | Repo Browser. Or just select the SVN Checkout command to get a working copy of the repo.

Comment: See URL examples here https://subversion.apache.org/quick-start#what-is-a-repository and here https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-basics-svn.html#tsvn-basics-svn-urls

Comment: From TortoiseSVN Manual: The file:// access method is normally used for local access, although it can be used with UNC paths to a networked host. The URL therefore takes the form file://hostname/path/to/repos. **For the local machine, the hostname portion of the URL is required to be either absent or localhost. For this reason, local paths normally appear with three slashes**, file:///path/to/repos.